# Android - Start LoginActivity with no possibility to return back with back button

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity that handles users login.
When user logs in he is forwarded to another activity. But when he presses "back" button he is back to login screen despite he is logged already. How can I avoid that behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear activity stack after user is logged in or use noHistory flag. Start login activity with intent that has these flags : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Here is one way to do it

```
Intent afterLogin = new Intent(this, AfterLoginActivity.class);
login.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(afterLogin);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you mind providing a code example for clearing activity stack?

Answer (score 0):

You just add this function in your second activity it will give your desired...All the best it will work 100%   All the best

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // You should write the super function or finish() here...
}
```